# HTML CSS - Font size oversized when shown on windows phone

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-8

I'm actually creating a newsletter. When i open the email into outlook, outlook web access, the layout is exactly the same as the one i built. 
Yet when I open the same email in my windows phone 8 font size is not respected and the email has no longer the same layout.

Do you have any kind of suggestion ?
I have this css instruction in my  tag. (-ms-text-size-adjust: none;)

```
body {
            background-color: #f9fbf4;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
        }
```

I also put this kind of css in the style span but it doesnt work

```
<span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Georgia,"sans-serif"; color: white; font-size-adjust: none;'>Hello</span>
```

Comment: I guys ! I find a solution. I add an <img /> tag, just before the </body> tag. This image is a basic blank pixel 1px width & height : and it works correctly.
Not sure that's the perfect solution but it actually solved my problem !

Answer (score 1):

This might have something to do with the viewport size on the device. You can try setting the initial scale to see if that resolves the issue.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;>
```

Comment: Thanks but it not working :( - i find the solution, i will edit the post