# Windows phone internet explorer enlarge text in one td

Tags: html, css, windows-phone

The problem is, that I have table for content with 3 td's, side td is 200px wide and the middle one width isn't defined, everything seems great on computer browsers (even internet explorer), but when it comes to testing on windows phone browser, in middle td text is much bigger, I'd would say twice as big as it should be and nothing seems to fix that, yes I tried writing font-size value to it in css, but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Sorry that I can't supply a screenshot from my windows phone because of broken power button, I'm using standard windows phone 8.1 internet explorer.

CSS of the table

```
#content_table {
    width: 1024px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#content_table td:not(:last-child) {
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}

#content_table #side_content {
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#content_table #main_content {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.side_content_title {
    background: #c9cbce;
    border-top: solid 2px #535f7c;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #535f7c;
    text-align:center;
    width: 200px;
    color: #353c4c;
    padding: 2px 0;
}

.side_content {
    background: rgba(243,243,243,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    width: 190px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #535f7c;
    color: #535f7c;
}

.main_content_title {
    background: #c9cbce;
    border-top: solid 2px #535f7c;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #535f7c;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 30px;
    color: #353c4c;
}

.main_content {
    background: rgba(243,243,243,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #535f7c;
    color: #535f7c;
}
```

HTML part

```
<table id="content_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="side_content">
                <div class="side_content_title">title</div>
                <div class="side_content"><br/><br/></div>
            </td>
            <td id="main_content">
                <div class="main_content_title">title</div>
                <div class="main_content">
                    Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td id="side_content">
                <div class="side_content_title">title</div>
                <div class="side_content"><br/><br/></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you supply a screenshot plus the code perhaps so we can see your problem? Also, what browser are you using on your windows phone, asuming this is a webbased problem?

Comment: @Dorvalla sorry that I can't include screenshots, but I edited my main post with CSS and HTML code

Comment: What screensize are you using? 
Also this **width** will exceed your screensize `#content_table {
    width: 1024px;`
This will let you view any screensize which you can then screenshot. New users can't add images but can link to an image already uploaded http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Comment: do you have a responsive css file or any other css files?

Comment: @Mousey I'm not using responsive css file

This template is more for computer user, but while I didn't made responsive template, it'll be for phone users too, and td with really large text can be disgusting.

I'm using 1920x1080 resolution on my computer, and if I access website from screenfly on my phone, it all seems normal like on computer without extra large text

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mousey for helping, and pointing out to previously answered question. Setting view-port for device width could help if I wouldn't used few fixed position objects, but adding

```
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
```

to body fixed text-size problem without messing up with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line `font-size: 16px;` from this code should render will all `<td>` using the same font size

```
#content_table #main_content {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align:top;
 }
```

I think you are finding the phone automatically shrinks the font on smaller devices -  except when it is manually specified in the code. 16px will look large on a mobile.

Setting the `view-port` may also help -  see [HTML CSS - Font size oversized when shown on windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186829/html-css-font-size-oversized-when-shown-on-windows-phone-solved) for font-size issues on windows phone

**Edit** from the link above, using this fixed the problem as EDWcode stated.

`-ms-text-size-adjust: none;`

Comment: I added font-size to there after I saw that there's a problem for a probable solution, but that didn't worked.

View-port seems to fix text-size related problem, but aswell messes up fixed elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use belo code in the body tag or to the main table

```
-ms-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Comment: you pasting code directly from the link I gave you as an answer? Normally if it's a small thing you would create a comment rather than an answer on SO. (You can comment on your own posts)